# Subclassing SLComposeViewController designated initializer error

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm trying to create a subclass of `SLComposeViewController` to make it easier to use in my case. When I try to create a `required init` and call `super.init(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)` I get the following error:

`Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'SLComposeViewController'`

But when I check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html), there is nothing indicating that there is a designated initializer - so I went to its superclass, `UIViewController` the designated initializer is `super.init(nibName: String?, bundle: NSBundle?)`. But implementing this doesn't allow me to set the `serviceType` of the `SLComposeViewController` since its a `get` property.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I not subclass `SLComposeViewController`?

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Social

enum ShareType {
    case FB, Twitter
}

class ShareViewController: SLComposeViewController {

    var shareType: ShareType!

    required init(shareType: ShareType) {
        self.shareType = shareType

        switch shareType {
        case .FB:
            super.init(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        case .Twitter:
            super.init(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        }

    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using an extension:

```
enum ShareType {
    case FB, Twitter
}

extension SLComposeViewController {

    convenience init(shareType: ShareType) {

        switch shareType {
        case .FB:
            super.init(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        case .Twitter:
            super.init(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        }

    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
let twitterSheet = SLComposeViewController(shareType: .Twitter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `super.init()` to your `init()`. 
I know it seems simple, but that's what the compiler is complaining about. I haven't used `SLComposeViewController`, but I've run into that with other classes.

Comment: Okay. If nobody provides a solution before then, I'll have some time to dig in in a few hours.

Comment: Okay, I imagine I've done all the beating of head and gnashing of teeth that you've done, and I still can't figure out how to accomplish what you want. From the errors the compiler gives me, it seems to think `init!(forServiceType serviceType: String!)` is a convenience initializer. That directly contradicts the documentation. I wish you luck. If you do solve this, please post back in here.

Comment: I'm am completely stumped still. Guess for now until I want to clean up my code more I'm gonna leave it as it is - ugly